# How do I submit forms with the Enter key without a submit button

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit, enter

I have jQuery go though all the submit buttons with the class *button*, and turn them each into an anchor element with the class button.

```
$("input.button").each(function(i) {

    var anchorButton = $("<a class='"+this.className+"' href='#'>"+this.value+"</a>")



    anchorButton.click(function(eventObject) {

        $(this).blur().prev("input.hidden").click();

        return false;

    });



    $(this)

        .after(anchorButton)

        .addClass("hidden")

        .removeClass("button pill-left pill-center pill-right");

});
```

I can then style the anchor element with CSS, cross-browser-ly. There's only one problem. Whenever I press the Enter key on form input elements, the form doesn't submit. However, if I un-hide the submit button, it works again. In conclusion, I can't get the Enter/Return key to submit the form unless I have a submit button visible (display != none).

How can I get the form to submit when I press Enter when I have the submit button hidden?

Comment: may I as why you transform the form's submit buttons into anchors?

Comment: The reason I changed input[type=submit] elements into anchors is so I can style them and get around Internet Explorer's quirks on button elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input.button").keydown(function(event) {
   if(event.keyCode == 13)
      $("...find the form...").submit();
});
```

This should work.

If it doesn't try this:

```
   $("..find the input button you hide..").css('position', 'absolute')
         .css('top', '-1000px');
```

This is better than the proposed `visibility: hidden` solutions since if you set the visibility to hidden the button will still "take up space".

Comment: Okay admitted - though the question specifically asked about hiding the submit button :)

Comment: @Roopesh: The question was how to make the form submit by pressing the Enter key when the *submit button was already hidden*.

Comment: True the visibility CSS property is not appropriate.

I already have the code that submits the form when I press the anchor element. What I need is to keep the Enter key's default behavior on input[type=text] elements.

I guess my solution would be to use absolute positioning instead of the display property. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Andreas: Shouldn't the selector be `input[type=text]` instead of `input.button` ?

Comment: @Stain, not at all. First, input[type=text] is for text boxes; I believe you meant input[type=button], but this would work in IE6. The reason I use a class so for IE compatibility (IE cannot recognize CSS attribute selectors).

I gave the absolute positioning alternative a try. It's definitely a solution! However, I'm still open to other solutions.

Comment: My suggestion is to use andreas' code but instead use $('form').delegate('*',keydown', callback'). This should only fire when the form is focused. The follow up code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an ordinary `form` in your HTML, including a submit `action` attribute. Then you'll get the browser's default behaviour and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> within the form will submit it. Then you don't have to use jQuery to bind event handlers to all your submit buttons.

You can test it with this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/esodu3).

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the visibility to hidden instead of display to none?

Answer (score -1):

Try visibility=hidden